# OpenGL: is glUniformLocation constant?

Tags: opengl

I couldn't find anywhere that stated this explicitly, but can I do:

```
unsigned int someUniform = 0;
unsigned int anotherUniform = 0;

glUseProgram(1);
someUniform = glGetUniformLocation(1, "uniformLocation");
glUniform3f(someUniform, 1, 1, 1);

glUseProgram(2);
anotherUniform = glGetUniformLocation(2, "anotherUniform");
glUniform3f(anotherUniform, 1, 1, 1);
```

And in the next frame, I just call:

```
glUseProgram(1);
glUniform3f(someUniform, 1, 1, 1);

glUseProgram(2);
glUniform3f(anotherUniform, 1, 1, 1);
```

I tested a bit and it did remain constant, but I have only two programs and I don't think I call anything complex.

Do I need to get the uniformLocation every frame, or can I find it's location once and be sure that's always the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you understand two things you should be good to go:

1. Uniform locations are established after linking shaders

   - They are assigned only to uniforms that are actually referenced in code, and do not change unless you change the linking.
2. Uniform locations are per-program states

   - It bothers me that you have poorly named uniform locations floating around at this scope... which uniform belongs to which program is needlessly difficult to understand in this example.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't recompile the shaders/relink the program, uniforms will stay constant.